# How to test multiple floating messages with the same content in cypress?

Tags: javascript, facebook, testing, cypress, assertion

I am fairly new to cypress and practicing its functionalities on Facebook app. I am having an issue on testing these following scenarios:

1.When clicked on First Name, this floating dialog should be visible.
2.Validating the text in the dialog box to be 'What's your name?'.
3.When clicked on Last Name, again a floating box with the same content "What's your name?" should be visible.

Now I am able to test the first two scenario with this.

```
cy.get('[name="firstname"]').click();//i)-> Click on the firstname
        cy.get('[name="lastname"]').click();//ii)-> Click on the last name    
        cy.get('[name="firstname"]').click(); //iii)-> This will triggers the error message popup for firstname 
        cy.contains('What\'s your name?').should('be.visible').and('contain','What\'s your name?');// Checking the message popup should be displayed and its message is 'What's your name'
        cy.get('[name="lastname"]').click();//v)-> This will trigger the error message popup for lastname
    
        cy.contains('What\'s your name?').should('be.visible').and('contain','What\'s your name?');//vi)-> Checking for that message but not working
```

But in the third scenario, it is showing the error. I tried to access the element using id but it was showing not found.
[image: Error Message]
[image: Facebook Page]

Answer (score 2):

I think `cy.contains('What\'s your name?')` is catching the message from firstName field which was activated from the initial two commmands but hidden when you navigated to the lastName field (but still remains in the page).

Specify which one you want

```js
cy.get('div:contains(What\'s your name?)').eq(1).should('be.visible')  // .and(contain) not needed
```

In case that quote in the text distorts the selection you may need to go with `cy.get('div:contains(your name?)').eq(1)`.

Don't use `cy.contains('What\'s your name?')` it will only ever return the first one it finds.

The Facebook page is not very tester friendly, usually you can request the page elements have some test id's added so you can go directly to then.

Another way to tackle the anonymous popup stuff is just to grab the last thing added to the page, like

```js
cy.get('body')
  .children()
  .last()
  .should('contain', 'What\'s your name?')
  .should('be.visible')
```

Comment: 1. I absolutely agree with the reasoning behind the error but I am not able to assert the second "What's your name?" to be visible. 2. The first one is not Working it is showing not visible. The error is "
This element <div.uiContextualLayer.uiContextualLayerLeft> is not visible because its parent <div.uiContextualLayerPositioner._572t.uiLayer.hidden_elem> has CSS property: display: none"

Comment: The second one is also not working because again i think the problem with its visibility. The error is "This element <div.uiContextualLayerPositioner._572t.uiLayer> is not visible because it has an effective width and height of: 486 x 0 pixels."

Comment: Could you please tell me how to tackle this problem?

Comment: Yes, change the index number in `.eq(1)` until it works - obviously one of them is showing.

Comment: yeah I tried like 2 inputs because I thought only for firstname and lastname, but it turns out there are 8 elements which was matching. .eq(5) works for it. But I want to ask is there wo way to select it using selector?

Comment: I must say I'm dubious about the form having 8 "What\'s your name?" prompts.

Comment: Yup I was also not noticing that but when you pointed out that try all of them, one will be showing. I noticed and then brute forced it.